# To get device sim number's ID in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, device

In my application i want to retrive the device sim number's ID.

Help me,

Regards,
Sampath

Answer (score 1):

```
SIMCardInfo.getIMSI();
```

[SIMCardInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/SIMCardInfo.html)